# jQuery event on a specific DropDownList option

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am very new to JQuery - I looked but could not find answers simple enough for my issues...
I have HTML drop down list (generated by a db file) with an ID on a selection common to all lists. It is on this "Add a New" option that I would like to trigger an event that will immediately slide open a div that will allow input & update of a new name to the list.

```
<select name="NAME" id="NMDROP">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="JOE">Joe</option>
<option value="BOB">Bob</option>
<option id="ADDNM" value="ADD">Add a New Name</option>
</select>
```

This is the jQuery I am hoping will allow me to call an update pgm.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //Jquery for Adding a SalesPerson
    $("#ADDNM").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":clicked")) {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "Update.pgm",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "task": "ajax_addsp",
                    "ajax_add": 'Y',
                    "NAME": NAME
                },
                success: function () { alert("success:");
                },
                error: function () {  alert("error on Add a New Name " + data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am confident that many of you will be able to spot my fundamental errors.  I am not even sure if this is a click or a change event, I have seen it both ways on this site.

Comment: Is the ID `ADDNM` unique?

Comment: @j08691 seems you are right, its a global attribute

Comment: @j08691 roasted have right. Option didn't have attribute `id`. Look: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Comment: @WooCaSh - no, roasted doesn't "have right". It's a valid attribute. Did you even read the page you linked to? It says right there that global attributes are valid on option elements, and the ID is a global attribute.

Comment: @j08691 Yes. you have right. My bad.

Comment: @Sooze Are my code was helpful and working? Can you give us any feedback please?

Comment: @j08691 - yes it is a unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using click, use the change event on your dropdown and check if the selected value is "ADD".

```
$("#NMDROP").on("change", function(e) {
    if($("#NMDROP").val() == "ADD") {
        //ajax method here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
$("#NMDROP").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'ADD'){
        //rest of code
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fNzTQ/)**

Comment: To try & see if I am detecting the event at all I used your code like this:

Comment: I'm sorry to be so thick - because no I do not have it working yet!!